# Import data website, when Xpath or regexpr is not working: will use JSON

Tags: html, regex, xpath, web-scraping

I want to retrieve data from the following website: https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/B4B:GR

I do not have a lot of knowledge of webs craping and html so I will try to explain my problem step by step.

The webpage has data under `quarterly` and `annual` (bottom page). But the issue is that the data from both has the same name: `div class= "value__01a1ae38"`. This is the same for `Revenue` `net income`, `profit margin` for both `quarterly` and `annual` data .

The only thing that changes between the quarterly and annual is:

When quarterly is selected:

```
<div class = "bb-tab quarterly item__4b54920e selected">
<div class ="bb-tab annual item__4b54920e">
```

When annual is selected:

```
<div class = "bb-tab quarterly item__4b54920e">
<div class ="bb-tab annual item__4b54920e selected">
```

Furthermore, the data is not stored as a child of class shown above so I cannot use Xpath to get to the data from here.

So the issue is that I cannot use simple RedExp because they are all the same class, and cannot use Xpath since I do not know how to reach this data since it is not a child of class that changes.

Anybody know how to retrieve the data that is showed when `annual` or `quarterly` is selected?

I added a screenshot so its easier to visualize what I am talking about. It shows the `annual` data from `income statement`

[image: Bloomberg webpage]

PS: This is how far I got by using the class name:

the following works to retreive data from quarterly:

```
=transpose(IMPORTXML("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/B4B:GR","//*[@class='value__01a1ae38'] "))
```

returns:

```
6,006.00    -87 -1.45%  17,254.00   15,576.00   43.18%  -706    -20 7216,006.00 -87 -1.45%  17,254.00   15,576.00   43.18%  -706    -20 721
```

However this way it is impossible to retrieve the data from annual

**Edit 22-07**

Using this link: https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/report/income/EQT/B4B%3AGR/annual?locale=en&currency=EUR

with this code you wrote `=Transpose(Split(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMPORTDATA(P11)),".+?2019-09-30""value:(.+?)}].","$1,"),","))`

Output with this code:

```
27082
421
1.5545
```

When I want to have the data from year 2018, I changed the code to
`=Transpose(Split(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMPORTDATA(P11)),".+?2018-09-30""value:(.+?)}].","$1,"),","))`

This gives the following output:

```
26792}{"dateTime":"2019-09-30"value:27082
333}{"dateTime":"2019-09-30"value:421           
1.2429000000000001}{"dateTime":"2019-09-30"value:1.5545
```

It begins with the correct value `26792` but then adds all the 2019 values to the answer. I have been playing with the `replace` part of the function but was unsuccessful to only show the 2018 data. Could you try to help me understand how exactly the `regexpreplace` function works? And why it would add the 2019 values and not the 2018 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data from the loaded JSONs in the background with `IMPORTDATA`. Then use formulas (`ARRAYFORMULA`, `JOIN`, `REGEXREPLACE`, `SPLIT`) in order to manipulate the imported data and retrieve the values of interest. You'll need the following urls :

```
https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/report/income/EQT/B4B%3AGR/annual?locale=en&currency=EUR
https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/report/balance/EQT/B4B%3AGR/annual?locale=en&currency=EUR
https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/report/cash/EQT/B4B%3AGR/annual?locale=en&currency=EUR
```

And the following formula in cell B9 :

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B3));".+?2019-09-30""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B4));".+?2019-09-30""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B5));".+?2019-09-30""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;");";")
```

Output :

[image: Bloomberg]

If you need to work with the values, clean the result with this formula in B10 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B3));".+?2019-09-30""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B4));".+?2019-09-30""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B5));".+?2019-09-30""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;");";");".";","))))
```

Side note : I'm based in Europe. So you'll probably need to replace ";" with "," in the formulas.

**EDIT** : To make the annual part automatic, two of the several options (with function `YEAR` and `NOW` of `QUERY` or with `YEAR` and `TODAY` of Sheets) :

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B3));".+?"&YEAR(TODAY())-1&".+?""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B4));".+?"&YEAR(TODAY())-1&".+?""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B5));".+?"&YEAR(TODAY())-1&".+?""value:(.+?)}].";"$1;");";")
```

or

```
=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B3));"}"));"select * WHERE Col1 contains (YEAR(NOW())-1)");".+value:(.+)";"$1")))&";"&TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B4));"}"));"select * WHERE Col1 contains (YEAR(NOW())-1)");".+value:(.+)";"$1")))&";"&TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B5));"}"));"select * WHERE Col1 contains (YEAR(NOW())-1)");".+value:(.+)";"$1")));";")
```

Output :

[image: Auto.Annual]

**EDIT 2** :

To select a specific year, use the following regex in the `REGEXREPLACE` formula :

```
^.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+$
```

With `$1;$2;$3;` groups as substitutes. Just change the value of the year in the regex (for e.g. : `2018` for `2017`) to fetch another year.

Formula used in B9 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B2));"^.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+$";"$1;$2;$3;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B3));"^.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+$";"$1;$2;$3;")&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;IMPORTDATA(B4));"^.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+?2018-.+?:(.+?)}.+$";"$1;$2;$3");";");".";",")*1)
```

Output :

[image: NeWReg]

Comment: Thanks @E.Wiest for the help! it works :) I heard of Json before but never got it to work. I am going to play around with it to understand it better. I finally found the links under 'XHR', is this where you get it too? Furthermore, could you help me brainstorm how I could always import the latest data? Now it will import with '2019-09-30'. But in a year this will be outdated. Is it possible to insert the latest date or something?

Comment: hi there! I have one more question about your solution. I am trying to select the data from a certain year separately. But I cannot make it work. I have edited my question. Could you please help me understand the RegExpReplace? and how I can make it work?

Comment: Post has been edited with a solution (a cleaner regex to select a specific year).